# Slicehost verses Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, slicehost

What are the plus's and minus's of both of these companies and services?

Comment: IMHO a fishing expedition that should be closed as too open-ended and argumentative. Without any constraints at all, a comparison between plain Xen VMs and EC2 with all Amazons additional services (MySQL, SimpleDB, S3 etc) either becomes nonsense, or a small novel. (And OP did ask for comparison of "companies and services").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my research Amazon had a few more services that Rackspace/Slicehost did not (like SimpleDB.)  Amazon is a little more expensive for the server instances, but Rackspace charges more for bandwidth.  You might look at one of the company that provide an abstraction layer to the services so you can use either or both.  I've heard Rightscale is quite nice, though I have not tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Slicehost vs. Amazon EC2 is not really fair.

I'd check out [Linode](http://www.linode.com/?r=c76fb744149d3f658d38406bb2606bb783bf3d23) vs. Amazon EC2. Anyways, my company recently decided to use Linode due to the simplicity of use and the appeal of better I/O rates. Amazon is better if your requirements are minimal or excessive in any sense. Linode/Slicehost win out if you need quality I/O rates. There are more advantages/disadvantages but I still prefer Linode.

Comment: Also, check out http://journal.uggedal.com/vps-performance-comparison and http://blog.kevmod.com/2009/12/linode-vs-ec2-vs-shared-hosting-vs-dedicated/